# I'm trying to do a http get request to get data from my backend Larval, MYSQL I have created the API in Laravel but cant display the data in Angular

Tags: mysql, laravel-8, angular13

I'm new to programming and new advise please here is my code

employees component

import { DataService } from './../../service/data.service';

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

```
selector: 'app-employees',

templateUrl: './employees.component.html',

styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css'
```

]})

export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {

employees: any

```
constructor(private dataservice: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}
getEmployeesData() {
    this.dataservice.getData().subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.employees = res;
    });
}
```

}

*data.service.ts*

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

```
getData: any;


constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees')
};
```

}

HTML

```
<thead>

    <tr>

        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Surname</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Salary</th>

    </tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

    <tr *ngFor="let emp of employees">
        <th scope="row">{{emp.id}}</th>
        <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.surname}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.email}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.salary}}</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: Sorry im trying to format my code better so that its more readable

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things, that cause the Data not to show up.

data.service.ts:

Your fetching the Data in the Constructor but you do ignore the return Value of your call. I suggest you do the call in a separate function that will be called if the data is needed.

```js
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

loadAllEmployees(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees');
}
```

Employees Component:

It seems, that you do not call the getEmployeesData function. Therefore your employees never get any Data.

```js
employees: any

constructor(private dataservice: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.getEmployeesData();
}
getEmployeesData() {
    this.dataservice.loadAllEmployees().subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.employees = res;
    });
}
```

With this setup, your data should load and be displayed.
Besides that, I would suggest you define the Type of the Employee and do not work with any. It does make it easier to read and understand your code. You are also less likely to get any Errors regarding types.

Comment: Hi Motscha thank you for your feedback, i have taken note of what you said and updated my coding accordingly , I also realized after 3hours that my method was outside of my class bracket hence it could not display the data,

Comment: how can i upvote your fix because it works now, when I clicked the upvote it does not vote

Comment: Glad I could help you.
You don't upvote but rather accept the answer. You can see here [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) what is it all about and how to do it.